# Fetch string between long text area

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have the long text area like below.

```
Most recent role information:
==================================================
  Job Title        : National Practice Manager
  Company Name     : NEC
  Time in Role     : 0 years 0 months
  New to Workforce :
```

I need to fetch the value of Job tile (National Practice Manager) and Company Name (NEC) from above text area. I tried using IndexOf. But the location of Job tile and Company Name always be not same. Can anyone please help to parse the string from long text area.

Comment: is this a .txt file? or a string? or what is this????

Comment: Yes, you can use `indexOf` which searches for where those Strings are.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regexp with matching groups:

```
Job Title\w+:\w(.*)
```